# Vector of comma separated strings to matrix

Tags: r

I have been working on this since an hour and I feel like I ran against a wall: I want to transform a vector of comma separated strings to a matrix.

I have a vector like:

```
'ABC,DFGH,IJ'
'KLMN,OP,DFGH,QR'
'ST,ABC'
```

I want to get a matrix like

```
ABC DFGH IJ KLMN OP QR ST
1   1    1  0    0  0  0
0   1    0  1    1  1  0
1   0    0  0    0  0  1
```

Sample data:

```
myvec<-c('ABC,DFGH,IJ','KLMN,OP,DFGH,QR','ST,ABC')
```

Base R answers are welcome as well. I might need this trick for some bigger datasets again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another base R solution:

```
> myvec<-c('ABC,DFGH,IJ','KLMN,OP,DFGH,QR','ST,ABC')
> mv <- strsplit(myvec,",")
> u <- unique(unlist(mv))
> t(sapply(mv, function(x) u %in% x)*1)
# output without colnames
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7]
[1,]    1    1    1    0    0    0    0
[2,]    0    1    0    1    1    1    0
[3,]    1    0    0    0    0    0    1
> r <- t(sapply(mv, function(x) u %in% x)*1)
# adding colnames 
> colnames(r) <- u
> r
     ABC DFGH IJ KLMN OP QR ST
[1,]   1    1  1    0  0  0  0
[2,]   0    1  0    1  1  1  0
[3,]   1    0  0    0  0  0  1
```

Comment: instead of `%in%` you can use `match` directly but this turns out to be a bit cumbersome: `r <- t(!is.na(sapply(mv, match, x=u)))*1`

Comment: Yeah in addition in doesn't bring anything in terms of speed. Anyways your way was the fastest and it is intuitive as well - if you understand the R logic that is :D

Answer (score 1):

```
library(tidyverse)

myvec<-c('ABC,DFGH,IJ','KLMN,OP,DFGH,QR','ST,ABC')

data.frame(myvec) %>%                # create a data frame
  mutate(id = row_number(),          # create row id (helpful in order to reshape)
         value = 1) %>%              # create value = 1 (helpful in order to reshape)
  separate_rows(myvec) %>%           # separate values (using the commas; automatically done by this function)
  spread(myvec, value, fill = 0) %>% # reshape dataset
  select(-id)                        # remove row id column

#   ABC DFGH IJ KLMN OP QR ST
# 1   1    1  1    0  0  0  0
# 2   0    1  0    1  1  1  0
# 3   1    0  0    0  0  0  1
```

Comment: Any idea why your answer returns an error when I load only `dplyr` and `tidyr`? I had to install `tidyverse`, then it worked. Maybe has something to do with package versions...

Comment: Where was the error and what was the error message? Does it work now that you updated the packages if you load only `dplyr` and `tidyr`?

Comment: The error was `Error in rank(x, ties.method = "first", na.last = "keep") : 
  argument "x" is missing, with no default`. Yep with the new versions it works. Must have been one of the `tidyr` functions; because the `dplyr` package wasn't updated with the `install.packages("tidyverse")` command.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this with **BASE R:**

**Data:**

```
myvec<-c('ABC,DFGH,IJ','KLMN,OP,DFGH,QR','ST,ABC')
```

**Solution:**

```
unq <- unique(strsplit(paste0(myvec,collapse=","),",")[[1]])
sapply(unq, function(x)grepl(x,strsplit(myvec,","))+0)
```

**Output**:

```
> sapply(unq, function(x)grepl(x,strsplit(myvec,","))+0)
     ABC DFGH IJ KLMN OP QR ST
[1,]   1    1  1    0  0  0  0
[2,]   0    1  0    1  1  1  0
[3,]   1    0  0    0  0  0  1
```